# Ubuntu + Lazarus + Indy ошибка при активации IdHTTPServer

Tags: ubuntu, lazarus, indy

Линукс знаю облачно.

Linux версии: ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64. Поставил последнюю версию Lazarus'a скачав с офф сайта: 1.6.0. Скачал и подключил библиотеку Indy 10 с офф сайта: http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/fpc/index.en.aspx

Программки типо ShowMessage('Hello World!'); Успешно компилируются и запускаются.

Нужно запустить локальный сервер на определенном порте. Делают это через IdHTTPServer:

```
IdHTTPServer1.DefaultPort:= 8080;
IdHTTPServer1.Active:= True;
```

И на строчке активации происходит ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жму "Continue" и программа закрывается.
Если жму "Break", то открывается модуль IdThread указывающий на строчку:

```
inherited Create(ACreateSuspended);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это все означает незнаю, и прошу у вас помощи как решить данную проблему.
Так же если даже указать исключение через try except end на туже строчку активации сервера, то даже он не срабатывает и программа закрывается.

Answer (score 1):

Перелопатив демки нашел решение.
Первое нужно добавить биндинг:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Binding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  IdHTTPServer1.DefaultPort:= 25000;
  Binding:= IdHTTPServer1.Bindings.Add;
  Binding.IP:= '127.0.0.1';
  Binding.Port:= 8080;
  IdHTTPServer1.Active:= True;
end;
```

И второе в исходнике проекта, убрать проверку  {$IFDEF UNIX} на модуль cthreads, т.е. до редактирования:

```
uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Interfaces,
  Forms,
  unit1;
```

После редактирования:

```
uses
  cthreads,
  Interfaces,
  Forms,
  unit1;
```

После этих манипуляций, сервер успешно запускается.